# Create publicly accessible webcal uri from .net core console application

Tags: .net, office365, icalendar

I have this code:

```
var calendar = new Calendar();

// Create a calendar event
var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
{
    Summary = "Meeting with Client",
    Description = "Discuss project details",
    Location = "Office",
    DtStart = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
    DtEnd = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)),
    IsAllDay = false
};

// Add the event to the calendar
calendar.Events.Add(calendarEvent);

// Serialize the calendar to iCalendar format
var calendarSerializer = new CalendarSerializer();
var serializedCalendar = calendarSerializer.SerializeToString(calendar);

// Display the iCalendar data (optional)
Console.WriteLine("iCalendar Data:");
Console.WriteLine(serializedCalendar);

// Generate WebCal URL
var webCalUrl = CalendarService.GenerateWebCalUrl(serializedCalendar);

// Display the WebCal URL
Console.WriteLine("\nWebCal URL:");
Console.WriteLine(webCalUrl);

Console.ReadLine(); // To keep the console window open for viewing the output
```

Now, my question is how to host this .ics file for free if there any options for it?
I tried with some .ics files to host it on OneDrive and GoogleDrive but they are using proxy links, and Im unable to subscribe to these calendars in Outlook 365.

Goal: Im trying to create proof of concept solution for syncing calendar from my .net core app to outlook calendar 365.
Im using iCal.Net nuget.